# Send file to Mule inbound-endpoint

Tags: file-upload, mule, endpoint

I'm trying to send a form with a file and two inputs to an Mule inbound-endpoint. I've got a custom-processor, and a flow defined like that:

```
<custom-processor class="informa.app.classifier.transformers.MyfileUploadProcessor" name="fileuploadprocessor"></custom-processor>
<flow name="httpTest">
    <http:inbound-endpoint
                    address="http://tango.privada.informa:11002/services/fileupload"></http:inbound-endpoint>
    <processor ref="fileuploadprocessor"/>
</flow>
```

In the class MyfileUploadProcessor:

public class MyfileUploadProcessor implements MessageProcessor {

```
    @Override
    public MuleEvent process(MuleEvent event) throws MuleException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String response = "success";

        MuleMessage mulemessage = event.getMessage();

        String countryCode = mulemessage.getInboundProperty("username");
        String sourceCode = mulemessage.getInboundProperty("password");
        InputStream input = (InputStream) mulemessage.getPayload();

...
```

And to test, a simple html:

```
<form action="http://tango.privada.informa:11002/services/fileupload" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p>Country Code :<input type="text" name="username" /></p>
   <p>Source Code :<input type="text" name="password" /></p>
   <p>File :<input type="file" name="payload" /></p>
   <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset"></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The issue is I can't create a file from the payload of the mulemessage and I don't know how to get the value of the inputs in the form...what I'm doing wrong? any clues?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the HTTP connector to use the `org.mule.transport.http.HttpMultipartMuleMessageFactory` in order to handle `multipart/form-data` HTTP POSTs.

For this, add the following to your configuration:

```
<http:connector name="httpConnector">
    <service-overrides messageFactory="org.mule.transport.http.HttpMultipartMuleMessageFactory"/>
</http:connector>
```

With this in place, the `payload` form field will become the streaming payload of the Mule message and all the other fields values will be in *inbound attachments* (any part header will be in *inbound headers*).

Answer (score 1):

Great answer from David (a life saver for me !! cudos david)
for what it is worth some extra items I didn't realize at first the httpConnector has to be used as http transport reference a full flow would be

```
<http:connector name="httpConnector" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS">
        <service-overrides
            messageFactory="org.mule.transport.http.HttpMultipartMuleMessageFactory" />
    </http:connector>

<flow name="AttachmentTestFlow1" doc:name="AttachmentTestFlow1">        
    <http:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="httpConnector" doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081"/>
    <component class="ProcessAttachment" doc:name="Java" />
</flow>
```

I was able to upload using jmeter adding two attachments, the first

- has a paramter name = "payload" and mime-type="multipart/form-data"
- the second has a user specificed name, e.g "attachment"

This can then be processed by a normal mule flow, or a component

```
public String process(@Payload String payload, @InboundAttachments("*") Map<String, DataHandler> headers  ) throws IOException{     
    InputStream in  = headers.get("attachment").getDataSource().getInputStream();
```

Comment: A life saver to me as well even after 2 years, thanks guys for your sharing of this bit of knowledge!